# Bulk delete items from AWS DynamoDB with only partition key (NOT DUPLICATE)

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I am trying to delete all items having a particular value as primary key 
For example: **groupName** is the **primary key** column on DynamoDB. There is one **groupVersion** column which is the sort key. 
I want to **delete all the items where groupName column's value is** **group123**

A simple **mysql** query would do like:

```
delete from table XYZ where groupName = 'group123';
```

I tried the below code but it always fails to delete with message: `The provided key element does not match the schema (Service: DynamoDb, Status Code: 400`

The code I have tried:

```
TableSchema<Group> TABLE_SCHEMA = StaticTableSchema.builder(Group.class)
    .newItemSupplier(Group::new)
    .addAttribute(String.class, a -> a.name("groupName")
            .getter(schema -> schema.getGroupName())
            .setter((schema, schemaName) -> {
                schema.setSchemaName(schemaName);
            })
            .tags(primaryPartitionKey()))
    .addAttribute(Long.class, a -> a.name("groupVersion")
            .getter(schema -> schema.getGroupVersion())
            .setter((schema, s) -> {
                schema.setSchemaVersion(s);
            })
            .tags(primarySortKey()))
    .addAttribute(String.class, a -> a.name("value")
            .getter(schema -> schema.getValue())
            .setter((schema, s) -> {
                schema.setValue(s);
            }))
    .build();

Region region = Region.US_EAST_1;
DynamoDbClient ddb = DynamoDbClient.builder()
        .region(region)
        .enableEndpointDiscovery()
        .build();

DynamoDbEnhancedClient client = DynamoDbEnhancedClient.builder()
        .dynamoDbClient(ddb)
        .build();

client.table(tableName, TABLE_SCHEMA).deleteItem(DeleteItemEnhancedRequest.builder()
    .key(Key.builder().partitionValue("group123").build())
    .build());
```

Using AWS Java SDK v2.
Maven version of SDK is **2.13.4**

Comment: Didn't find anything as such but yes the example of "DeleteItem" has only partition key specified to build the key and delete the item. I tried that example too but I get the same response


reference: https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/master/javav2/example_code/dynamodb/src/main/java/com/example/dynamodb/DeleteItem.java

Comment: Dynamodb does not support deleting items by partition key. What you can do though is to query by partition key, and then use BatchWriteItem to delete the items returned by your query (max 25 items at a time).

Comment: yeah doing the same for now.